# Index intersection issue in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongo 2.6.8 and have the following problem:

Collection `users` has indexes `_id_1` and `b_1`. When I perform query

```js
db.users.find({"$and": [
     {"b": {"$gt": ISODate("somedate")}}, 
     {"b": {"$lt": ISODate("anotherdate")}},
     {"_id": {"$gt": "somevalue"}}, 
     {"_id": {"$lt": "anothervalue"}},
]})
```

I expect that mongo will perform index intersection and will use intersected index, but it chooses only `b_1` index. When executing explain on this query allPlans section even doesn't contain intersected index, only `_id_1` and `b_1`.

Why does mongo not perform index intersection?

Comment: How big is the collection? Have you run an explain(true)? Does it show an index intersection plan was considered?

Comment: Collection size is a few gigabytes. When I wrote about `allPlans` I meant that explain was executed with `true` flag. And as I wrote I saw only 2 possible plans that mongo had tried: one with `_id_1` index and another with `b_1` index. Maybe it's worth to mention: my mongo instance is running in a cluster and has a few replicas.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could result from the fact, that you have two restrictions in your query on the same indexed key (`$gt` and `$lt` on `b` (and same for `_id`)). What happens to your explain if you change your query to the following. If It's using intersection I would be right:

```
db.users.find({"$and": [
     {"b": {"$gt": ISODate("somedate")}}, 
     {"_id": {"$gt": "somevalue"}}, 
]})
```

In this case using both restrictions on one index could be faster than using only one restriction of both indexes and use the intersection.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't use intersected index when having 1 restriction on each field. Still uses index `b_1` as the best one.